# Show some message every day at 08:00 AM with ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read my database get values, change my old message with new value and then show this newly message. I want to do this reading job at everyday 08:00. How can I know if clock is 08:00 AM? Need to control every second? or what else?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to note here is that you don't actually need to do this at 8am - you need to do it when the application is in use at 8am *or* the first time the application is in use after 8am - if, that is, you want to do this solely within your ASP.NET application.

You need to track when the message was last updated.

In ASP.NET in a suitable application startup event, call the update method - which should check to see if the value needs updating - and then set a timer (its been 5 years since I wrote the code to do this last, options will have changed) for the "next" 8am - when the timer fires, call your update method, set the timer again. So, if the app starts it will update if required, if its running the update will happen.

If you have more access to the server then create a windows service to do the update.

There are several options in between these two - create a page or a web service to trigger the update logic within the ASP.NET application and then use an external timer to open the page/call the web service at the scheduled time. The most appropriate solution depends on your hosting enviroment and the other resources available to you.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a windows service and schedule it for the time you require every day.